# Check if at least one input in array has a value using jQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to check if at least one of my inputs has a value. The code below is currently working to check if **all** inputs have a value, I need to just check if one in the array contains a value.

```
var returnValue = true;
var listOfInputs = [
    $("#entry_bg"),
    $("#entry_carbs"),
    $("#entry_bolus"),
    $("#entry_correction"),
    $("#entry_food"),
    $("#entry_notes")
];


listOfInputs.forEach(function(e) {
    if (!e.val()) {
        returnValue = false;
    }
});

if (!returnValue) {
    return false;
}
```

What can I do to achieve this? Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed that the simplest solution was to just check for an element that had a value and set `returnValue = true`.

```
var returnValue = false;
var listOfInputs = [
    $("#entry_bg"),
    $("#entry_carbs"),
    $("#entry_bolus"),
    $("#entry_correction"),
    $("#entry_food"),
    $("#entry_notes")
];

listOfInputs.forEach(function(e) {
    if (e.val()) {
        returnValue = true;
    }
});

if (!returnValue) {
    openErrorModal(".entry_submit", "Add Entry", "You must fill out at least one input in order to add an entry.", "#entry_modal");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This works, but is less efficient, since the `forEach` still continues to iterate the rest of the array, even if there was already a non-empty input found, which is kinda useless. The advantage of `.some` is that it exits as soon as the callback returns a truthy value, *and* it returns the boolean value of interest.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
return listOfInputs.some(function(e) {
    return e.val() != '';
});
```

Comment: Just notice you unaccepted this answer five months later. Was there any issue?

Answer (score 2):

You should check [`Array.protoype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some?v=example).

> `some()` executes the callback function once for each element present in the array until it finds one where callback returns a truthy value

```
const hasAtLeastOneValue = listOfInputs.some(input => !!input.val());
```